# An example of semi direct product of Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras, semidirect-product

Let $L$ be Lie algebra and $d: L \to L $ a derivation. Let we have a one-dimensional Lie Algebra generated by element $t$. What will be the semi direct product of $L$ with one-dimensional Lie algebra which act on it via derivation? 
In addition , how is the free  product of $L$ with one dimensional Lie algebra?

Comment: Are you asking for examples or for the definitions?

Comment: yes. I want an explicit example for that

Comment: Ok, which examples of Lie algebras with a derivation are you familiar with?

Comment: Heisenberg algebra or special linear lie algebra

Comment: Ok, and let's also pick a derivation.

Comment: If $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$ denotes a basis, then the inner derivations are in the form $ad(x)$ . we must define $ad(e_1) , ad(e_2) , ad(e_3)$.

Comment: No, we are not defining $ad(e)$, as that is already defined. We need to pick a derivation, so which inner derivation should we take? And for which of the Lie algebras?

Comment: For Heisenberg Lie algebras  we define derivation.

Comment: Derivations are defined in the same way for all Lie algebras. But we need to pick a specific one if we want to find an actual example.

Comment: Actually I do not know the meaning of via derivation in the above. According to the definition of semi direct product of $L$ and $S$ we have: $(s_{1},x_{1})(s_{2}x_{2}):=([s_{1},s_{2}],[x_{1},x_{2}]+ \theta (s_{1})x_{2}-\theta(s_{2})x_{2})$ such that $\theta:S\to Der L$. How $ \theta$ acts here? And here $Der L$ is a Lie algebra but I am confused of the homomorphism $\theta$ and its role?

Comment: "via derivation" just means that all elements are sent to derivations (rather than other endomorphisms which are usually allowed when taking a semidirect product).